# Process cannot access it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I got solution with three separated windows services. One services download files, second is taking the files and third one is loading to db. Sometimes during downlading files, second process is starting to play with it during its still downloading, or third process wants to load it but file is still parsing. I heard that Mutex could be resolution in my case but i am not sure how in this situation i could use it the other processes waits on files untill they are "free". Below i'll present you my code:

Downlading process part of code where file download is doing:
(in this case each file is downloading to specific location folder)

```
 For Each item In RemoteFiles
                            Try
                                session.GetFiles(item, DownloadFolder, True, transferOptions).Check()
                            Catch ex As Exception 
                            End Try
                        Next
```

Parsing win service process part of code which is parsing downloaded files:

```
 Dim ColumnFound As Boolean = False
            Using MyReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileToBeParsedPath)
                Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data
                With MyReader
                    .TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                    .Delimiters = New String() {","}

                    .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
                End With
```

After that process each file are migrated to ParsedFolder. But data from it is saved in files with .dat extension. And those files are used by my Loader engine.

How can i do some "lock on file" for instance for files which are during download process to prevent parser to take them under parsing process and wait? Can i make some centralized place where file status will be saved, so parser after take existing files into the list and then when is going to open and parse them will check and wait untill its free?? Please about your advice/code.

**EDITED:**

•Ftp two files but only watch one. For example send the files important.txt and important.finish. Only watch for the finish file but process the txt.

•FTP one file but rename it when done. For example send important.wait and have the sender rename it to important.txt when finished.

Comment: This is entirely normal.  Just don't use 3 separate processes, it doesn't help you and only causes problems that are pretty hard to solve.  One is enough.

Comment: i know one process would help with synlock as every operation would go step by step. But i would like to stay with this solution and wonder if there is any basic solution.workaround for that issue.

Comment: There is nothing basic about it.  Don't do it.

Comment: I Underground but ten IT world takę lot of Time.first part would download files ten parę IT and the load to data base. The reform i made one proces for ech of the operatora SO afer same files are download parser proces could start his job. IS there realy no pattern for IT? What i could imagine is if first download win service will find files and download them it could aware of second process to run. If so is it good way and how could it be possible

Comment: what do you think about solution - check my EDITED main post

Comment: There isn't a _basic_ solution, as you've designed in complexity from the start.  The simple solution would be to have one process doing this (possibly with 3 threads, if that's the way you want to structure it), but then you'd at least have shared memory where you could have various queues handing data from one thread to another.